# Profiling .Net core unit test run in CentOS 7.0

Tags: centos, .net-core, perf

I am trying to capture the profile data of a test run. As the title states, I am running .net core 2.X on CentOS. I am able to generate the *.map files. Grepping through the files' contents, I can see target source code mapped.

Subsequently I run:

```
dotnet test --no-build &
sudo perf record -p PID -g
```

After the test run finalizes and running "sudo perf report -f" I can not see any of the target symbols.

I know that dotnet test forks the test load to several subprocesses.

In short, I have two questions:

What am I missing? and does perf keep track of the subprocesses created by the PID under observation?

Thanks!

**edit 1**

What I have noticed is that the how-to instructions show *.map in the shared object column. My runs don’t. None of the blogs point out that a path has to be given.

Does perf look in /tmp by default for map files?

**Edit 2**

By launching the test run with the following command: “perf record dotnet test” I have been able to make perf to use the *.map files (they appear in the shared object column of Perf’s report) and generate a reasonable amount of data (as opposed to the tiny amount that I captured before) but the target symbols are still missing. It grabs the newton soft symbols from the same *.map but not my code

Comment: `perf` uses debug symbols, right? I wonder if `dotnet` has them...

Comment: I will check the path in the *.map files.

Comment: @omajid the perf*.map files generated by COMPlus_PerfMapEnabled are coming from the debug dir. the pdbs should be there. I will try a simple console app, as in the samples, to see if I get a different result. Or check tfs addons to see if there is something similar